# How to search user in active directory with sAMaccountName, where sAMaccountName is a concat of (firstinitial+lastName)+(regex)ending with any digits?

Tags: java, regex, active-directory

I want to search a user in Active Directory with sAMaccountName,where the sAMaccountName is firstName.substring(0,1)+lastName+ending with any digit.
Code Snippet:

```
 try {
      context=this.getADConnection();

      String returnedAtts[]={"givenName","sn"};
      String sAMAccountNameRegex=sAMAccountName+"\\d*";
      //String sAMAccountNameRegex=sAMAccountName+Pattern.quote("[0-9]*");
      SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
  searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
  searchControls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
  searchControls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
  searchControls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
  //String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(givenName=" +firstInitial+"*)(sn="+lastName+"))";
  String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user) (|(&(givenName=" +firstInitial+"*)(sn="+lastName+"))(sAMAccountName=("+sAMAccountNameRegex+"))) )";
  logger.info(className + privateMethodName + "  Searching User using filter : [" + searchFilter + "]");
  // Search for objects using the filter
  // Search for objects using the filter
      NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = context.search(SAMAccountNamePrePop.adSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);
      SearchResult searchResult = null;
      while(results.hasMoreElements()) {
      searchResult = (SearchResult) results.nextElement();
      logger.info(className + privateMethodName + " Search Result : [" + searchResult + "]");
      totalResults++;
      }`
```

Search filter used is

`String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user) (|(&(givenName=" +firstInitial+"*)(sn="+lastName+"))(sAMAccountName=("+sAMAccountNameRegex+"))) )";`

I have tried with following search filters for sAMaccountName,but none worked and gives following exceptions

1. `String sAMAccountNameRegex=sAMaccountName.Pattern.quote("\\d*");`

   `Exception is: [invalid escape sequence: [B@755c9b9c]`

   after passing values searchfileter looks like:

`[(&(objectClass=user) (|(&(givenName=C*)(sn=BOND3))(sAMAccountName=(CBOND3\Q\d*\E))) )]`

2. String sAMAccountNameRegex=sAMAccountName+"([0-9]*)$";

   `Exception is:[[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E5, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
      '']]`

   `after passing values searchfileter looks like:`

   `[(&(objectClass=user) (|(&(givenName=C*)(sn=BOND3))(sAMAccountName=(CBOND3([0-9]*)$))) )]`
3. String sAMAccountNameRegex=sAMAccountName+"\d*";

   `Exception:[[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001E5, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
       ''
   ]]`

   `after passing values searchfileter looks like:`

`[(&(objectClass=user) (|(&(givenName=C*)(sn=BOND3))(sAMAccountName=(CBOND3\d*))) )]`

So is it possible to query Ldap where the searchfilter is combination of string and regex?

Comment: Please format your code properly to make it more readable.

Comment: Can you point to the spot in the documentation of Active Directory where it says that LDAP search filters support regular expressions? Because I'm pretty sure they don't.

Comment: The [LDAP Syntax Filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN page, and the [simple examples page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) page from the technet site both indicate that there is *no* support for regexes in Active Directory search filters, so you're probably fighting a losing battle.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i tried and its working:

I am querying active directory with sAMaccountName*,i get the user and then handling the regex operation in my code locally

```
Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next());
String userId=attrs.get("sAMAccountNAme").toString();
if(userId.matches(sAMAccountNameRegex)){
    //business logic goes here
}
```